# Access form field attributes in templated Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I've been doing some custom forms with django but I don't get how to access attributes that a specific form field has attached via the forms.py.

```
def putErrorInTitle (cls):
init = cls.__init__

def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
    init(self, *args, **kwargs)
    if self.errors:
        for field_error in self.errors:
            self.fields[field_error].widget.attrs['title'] = self.errors[field_error][0]
            self.fields[field_error].widget.attrs['class'] = "help_text error_field"

cls.__init__ = __init__
return cls
```

That's how I attached the attibutes to the field.

```
<dl class="clearfix two">
 <dd>
  <label for="id_diagnosis">Diagnostico:</label>
   <select class="{{form.id_diagnosis.class}}" id="id_equipment_activity-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id_diagnosis" name="equipment_activity-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id_diagnosis">
    {% for x,y in form.fields.id_diagnosis.choices %}
    <option value="{{ x }}" {% ifequal form.id_diagnosis.data|floatformat x|floatformat %}selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ y }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    <option value="1000" {% ifequal form.id_diagnosis.data|floatformat '1000'|floatformat %}selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>Otro</option>
   </select>
 </dd>
 <dd class="vertical_center" id="optional_diagnosis"><label for="optional_diagnosis">Diagnostico opcional:</label>{{ form.optional_diagnosis }}</dd>
</dl>
```

I've been trying to access its attributes:

```
class="{{form.id_diagnosis.class}}", class="{{form.id_diagnosis.widget.class}}"
```

And I don't seem to find clear documentation about what's accessible and what's not. Really I would rather have old fashion documentation than django "friendly" one

Answer (score 16):

In other cases it can can be useful to set and get field attributes.

Setting in form's init function:

```
self.fields['some_field'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

... and accessing it in a template:

```
{{ form.some_field.field.widget.attrs.readonly }}
```

Comment: That is a great answer, but I would like to extend it.

If you are looping through the form fields and you need to add additional tags (because you are using bootstrap like me), you will need something like:
{% for field in form %}
{% if field.field.widget.attrs.class %}
 in order to determine if you need to add stuff

Answer (score 11):

It looks like you just want to display form errors for each field.
After the form is cleaned or validated in the view, the fields should contain
the error messages. So that you can display them in the template like so:

```
<form action='.' method='post'>
    ...
    <div class='a-field'>
       {{ form.field_1.errors|join:", " }}
       {{ form.field_1.label_tag }}
       {{ form.field_1 }}
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

If however you really want to display the form field attributes then you
can try something like:

```
{{ form.field_1.field.widget.attrs.maxlength }}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting he go the .errors route but still answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are correct, however, I'd like to add a note for those who are accessing form fields in a loop.

If you're doing this in a loop like this

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.field.widget.attrs.placeholder }} # field.field is the key here
{% endfor %}
```