# Checking for widget attribute in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd need to pass some data from my manually generated form to the template, and would need to check the presence of that information there.

I'm generating my form as such (in the `__init__` part):

```
for i in days_in_month:
    self.fields["info_%s" % i] = forms.ChoiceField(label="%s" % i.strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y"), 
    required=False, 
    choices=Information._meta.get_field('info').choices, 
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'something': 'test'}))
```

What I would like to do, is to check in the template whether the attribute `something` is set, and if so, display its value (in the example above: `test`).

Any idea?

I tried with `{{ field.attribute }}` as per [Access form field attributes in templated Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838415/access-form-field-attributes-in-templated-django) and the below:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {{ field.widget.attrs.something }}
{% endfor %}
```

... but that doesn't work (`invalid`).

Ultimately I want to do something similar to:

```
{% if field.widget.attrs.something %}{{ field.widget.attrs.something }}{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6):

That would be

```
{{ field.field.widget.attrs.something }}
```